# java get stored procedure response

Tags: java, stored-procedures

how do i get the Store procedure response in java  ? 
when i run this in SQL i get a response

```
DECLARE
result NUMBER;
begin

  result := apps.xx01_cpc_ap_pkg.xx01_create_invoice_f(8309, 4795, 146.00);
  dbms_output.put_line(result);
end;
```

this is my java code 
i tried many option - but i keep failing on how to fetch the  response 
in this part `resultSet.getInt(4))`

```
CallableStatement stmt = null;
String spCallRequest = "{? = call apps.xx01_cpc_ap_pkg.xx01_create_invoice_f(?, ?, ?  )}";
stmt = oraAppUtils.connection.prepareCall(spCallRequest);
stmt.setString(1,paymentRequest.healthFacilityCode);
stmt.setString(2,paymentRequest.batchId);               
stmt.setDouble(3,Double.parseDouble(paymentRequest.tariffAmount));
stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
System.out.println ("invoice id ="+resultSet.getInt(4));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok - just for documentation in case some else needs it...  this is the SP it has a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE APPS.XX01_CPC_AP_PKG
AS

PROCEDURE XX01_CREATE_INVOICE (P_HF_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
                               P_BATCH_ID IN VARCHAR2,
                               P_AMOUNT IN NUMBER,
                               x_invoice_id OUT NUMBER/*,
                               x_error_code OUT VARCHAR2,
                               x_error_msg  OUT VARCHAR2,
                               x_err_comments OUT VARCHAR2,
                               x_code OUT NUMBER,
                               x_source OUT VARCHAR2*/);

FUNCTION XX01_CREATE_INVOICE_F (P_HF_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
                               P_BATCH_ID IN VARCHAR2,
                               P_AMOUNT IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
```

so originaly i called the function - it didn't work - i change the code to the following code and it works

```
String spCallRequest = "BEGIN  apps.xx01_cpc_ap_pkg.xx01_create_invoice(?, ?, ?,? ); END ; ";
stmt = oraAppUtils.connection.prepareCall(spCallRequest);
stmt.setString(1,paymentRequest.healthFacilityCode);
stmt.setString(2,paymentRequest.batchId);
stmt.setDouble(3,Double.parseDouble(paymentRequest.tariffAmount));
stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
stmt.execute();
System.out.println ("invoice id ="+stmt.getInt(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

You did not call [ResultSet#next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())

**Reason**

From linked docs:

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

**Fix**

Your code should look like this:

```
stmt.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
if(resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println ("invoice id ="+resultSet.getInt(4));
} else {
    //this should not happen
}
```

Comment: thank you - but this is not helping i get the following   java.sql.SQLException: Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement: next

Answer (score 0):

Your question didn't explicitly mention JDBC as the API that you *must* use, so perhaps, you're open to third party utilities that work on top of JDBC? For example, [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org)'s [code generator can be used to generate stubs for all of your stored procedures](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq/). In your case, you could simply call the stub like this:

```java
int result = Xx01CpcApPkg.xx01CreateInvoiceF(
    configuration, // This object contains your JDBC Connection
    paymentRequest.healthFacilityCode,
    paymentRequest.batchId,
    Double.parseDouble(paymentRequest.tariffAmount)
);
```

These objects are generated by jOOQ:

- `Xx01CpcApPkg`: A class representing your PL/SQL package
- `xx01CreateInvoiceF()`: A method representing your stored function

Behind the scenes, this does exactly what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197641/521799) does, but:

- You don't have to work with strings
- You don't have to remember data types and parameter order
- When you change the procedure in your database, and regenerate the code, then your client code stops compiling, so you'll notice the problem early on

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.